# Bootstrap search expand not working if tabbed pane directly below it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the advanced drop down search provided here http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/advanced-dropdown-search

The problem is that the dropdown doesnt work in my existing page setup. I have a Bootstrap tabbed panel sitting right underneath the search box div

```
<div class="tabbable" id="indexTabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
    {% for index in allindexes %}
    {% set href = '#'+(index) %}
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        <li><a href={{href}}  class="active" data-toggle="tab">{{index|title}}</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li><a href={{href}} data-toggle="tab">{{index|title}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}        
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    {% for index in allindexes %}
    {% set href = '#'+(index) %}
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        <div class="tab-pane active" id={{index}}>AJAX request failed :(</div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="tab-pane" id={{index}}>AJAX request failed :(</div>
    {% endif %}        
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

If I do not have this tabbable class and use a generic div with content, it works fine. So the problem has something to do with having my tabbed panes. Any thoughts on how to resolve it. Ideally I would like my tabbed panes to slide down the page smoothly once the drop down on the search box is clicked. But my knowledge of CSS is rudimentary. Thanks

Comment: Where is your CSS?  You should make a working example of this.

Comment: I dont have a custom CSS besides the one provided in the link. I am using BootStrap